# Display Multipage PDF in UIWebView (Without Jerkiness): How does Safari do it?

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

If I load a PDF into a UIWebView:

```
if (!bundle)
    bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

NSString *filePath = [bundle
                      pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"pdf"];

UIWebView *webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds] autorelease];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[view addSubview:webView];


NSURL *pdfURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

the app acts just like Mobile Safari except when it has to do paging:

**Mobile Safari** pages without pause, showing the parts that it is rendering as checkerboard. **UIWebView**, in contrast, stops movement, and eventually jerks to the new position.

MobileSafari works nicely and UIWebView is unacceptable. What other options do I have for displaying a multipage PDF? Or do I need to handle the multipage aspect by myself using CGPDFPageRef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Just realized that the link refers to OS X programming, not iOS. Sorry.

Hello,

I tried out some similar code I ran into the same issue, so there is definitely some difference between the browser and the `UIWebView`.

In researching the problem I can across this **SO** thread: "[PDF in webview performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663967/pdf-in-webview-performance)" I think the last post may help you out.

**EDIT 2:**

The solution I would use is to convert your PDF into an image, and load that in an imageview with scrolling. Initially it might take a moment to load, but the scrolling action will be smooth and will not lag.

Comment: Very interesting link. In line with your Edit 2, I found this http://iosguy.com/2010/09/04 that works pretty nicely.

Comment: The QuickLook stuff is great. Thanks for getting me over there.