# Is it possible to load Office documents in Blackberry using Browser Field and WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, blackberry, browserfield

It is possible to load Office documents, PDF in UIWebView in iOS and I think same case applies to Android.

How about Blackberry and Windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding each platform:

- Yes, you can [load PDF into a UIWebView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663967/pdf-in-webview-performance)
- No, you cannot with Windows Phone 7. If a PDF is navigated to, you are prompted to save it,  which will then launch it in a dedicated viewer.
- For BlackBerry, I am  not sure, it looks like [it might be possible](http://forums.techarena.in/portable-devices/1393592.htm).